# why does antivirus seem to target specific numbers?

Tags: c++, antivirus

I was trying to make a program in c++ when I noticed something odd: everytime part of the program used a number near 2048 (I think somewhere above 2001 and less than 3000) it gets detected as a suspicious file and sent to the chest by "Avast!". changing the variable name seems to not make a difference. I was making a structure to add things to later
this is a snippet of it. I can guess where it's getting the detection from by the way it looks, but it never bothers the compiled executable unless it has a specific range of numbers
why might this be?

```
 int maxstep=2100;
 int maaa[2100];
 int curinst;

int main()
{
cout<<"Initializing maaa..."<<endl;

    for(int i=0; i<maxstep; i++)
    {
        maaa[i]=0;
        //cout<<"MEM:"<<i<<" "<<maaa[i]<<endl;
    }
cout<<"starting core"<<endl;
int stepcnt=0;
for(;;)
{
    if(stepcnt<maxstep)
    {
          curinst=maaa[stepcnt];

    }
    else
    {
        cout<<".";
    stepcnt=0;
    }
stepcnt++;
}
```

Comment: This is not a question about how to solve a programming problem.  It is a question about dysfunctional antivirus software.  Specifically, it's about Avast!, and should probably be brought up to their customer service department.

Comment: Is this when the program starts running, or after it's compiled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the virus software's defense, this code does do several things that seem odd. If I were rating a program on probability of being a virus, the code you posted seems pretty likely.

For starters, you declared your 3 primary variables as global variables, not within any local scope. It's uncommon, but it could be necessary.

Then you write the same value (0) to each element of the array. If this were intended to initialize the array, `memset` or `calloc` would be better to use. This implementation does lots of writes into global memory, each of which is probably a far store. A virus would do this if it were trying to corrupt program state.

Lastly, your program enters an infinite loop, in which is reads and writes from global memory. Each of these operations is probably a far load, followed by a far store. If the virus scanner has any sort of metric on far loads and far stores per second, your program will be way over the limit.

Comment: "far store", "far load", oh gosh I didn't hear that since 16bit times. Memory lane... (yes I'm kinda ironic here, those things don't exist any more since protected flat addressing became the norm some 20 years ago or so...) Anyway, glad to see some old timers around here. :)

Comment: You are right. Those operations died out many years ago and aren't specifically the problem here. I referenced them here just for an example of what "could" be happening, not what literally is. The internals of the compiler and virus software probably do treat accessing globals differently, but I don't know the specific instruction it may use.

Comment: Oh don't take me too seriously, just the mention of "far" vs "near" was enough to get me started. ;) As far as C++ goes there is **nothing** wrong with OP's code, but I don't know much about antiviruses since I don't use Windows. The whole thing was merely a jape. :)

Comment: No offense taken. Like yourself, I'm more surprised to hear someone else who remembered the "old ways."

Comment: Will you believe I still maintain 16 bit Windows code? :p Not mine, mind you, but still... Makes me cry every other day, especially since our newer developments exploit the full strength of C++11. xD

Comment: That's a bit of Jekyll & Hyde if you ask me. (sorry I meant to edit my previous comment but I was too late).